# Component Interaction Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Hi I have two components, a list component, and an edit component and service.
part of my Svc:

```
.....

    // Observable string sources
    private _updatedArray = new Subject<string>();

      // Service message commands
    setColDefs(columns: any) {
       this._updatedArray.next(columns);
       console.log(columns);
    }

getColDef(): Observable<any> {
    return this._updatedArray.asObservable();
}
```

And am calling my service in my list as below,

```
import { Svc } from '../services/mySvc.svc'

.....

this._listCompSvc.setColDefs(columns);
```

Until here its working perfect. I set the column values and the console.log in my svc showing the columns I want. but the issue comes in the edit component, when am getting the values(subscribing). my edit component code:

```
import { Svc } from '../services/mySvc.svc';
..

export class EditComponent implements OnInit{
    private _colDefs: any;
    constructor(
        private _editCompSvc: Svc
        ){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._editCompSvc.getColDef().subscribe(
          columns => {
              console.log(columns);
        });
    }
```

....

But somehow my console.log in edit, not displaying any data. I want to return my columns value here as per i set in my list component. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { routing } from './routes/myroute.route';
import { Svc } from './services/mySvc.svc'

import { ListComponent } from './actions/list.comp';
import { EditComponent } from './actions/edit.comp';

@NgModule({
    imports:
    [
        routing
    ],

    declarations:
    [
        ListComponent,
        EditComponent
    ],

    providers:
    [Svc]
})

export class Module { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is one way of doing it : load service in parent component and share it with all child

Parent Component

```
import { Svc } from '../services/mySvc.svc'
@Component({
.......
    providers: [Svc]
    template:`<child1></child1>
                <child2></child2>`
})
export class TerminalComponent implements OnInit {
```

In Both Child Component

```
import { Svc } from '../services/mySvc.svc'
@Component({
selector: 'child1',
......
})
export class Child1Component implements OnInit {
constructor(private _editCompSvc: Svc){}
}

import { Svc } from '../services/mySvc.svc'
@Component({
selector: 'child1',
......
})
export class Child2Component implements OnInit {
constructor(private _editCompSvc: Svc){}
}
```

2. Another way is to load service in route module / or the module in which all these components are loaded.
   Now there is no need to add this line `providers: [Svc]` in components.

   import { Svc } from '../services/mySvc.svc'
   @NgModule({
           .........
           providers: [Svc]
   }

Comment: Vivek no templates involved

Comment: Sorry Vivek its not a parent child component relationship either

Comment: Okay then you can do it by , 2nd way load provider in module , and not in components

Comment: yeah i provide my service in my module, and removed providing in my list and edit components. but i get `Error: DI Error
    at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError` error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139641/discussion-between-blackdaemon-and-vivek-doshi).

Answer (score 3):

You have added `Svc` as a provider of your `EditComponent`. So each edit component gets its own instance of the service, which is different from the one used by the list component.

To be shared, the service must be provided by a common parent component, or by a common parent module.

Comment: Oh Thanks JB! I dun have any parent component between these two. How can I achieve it in that case?

Comment: Now in parent component add [provider] but not in the child , and call those via DI in child.

Comment: JB, I have provided in my module, but i get, `Error: DI Error
    at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError` error

Comment: Choose the module which is parent to both the components , worst case app.module . But since both are related, there should be a parent module which contains both these components